# IIS change request timeout will affect all web app

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have 5 web apps host in IIS6, I need to change the timeout from 120 seconds to 500 seconds.  May I know any impact on all those web apps host under IIS like performance, security issues?

Comment: As far as I know, this does not affect performance, security, but the performance of the application will affect the request timeout.

Comment: 1) IIS 6 is end of life for many years. When you use an obsolete product like that, there isn't much to discuss about security as it won't be secure at all. 2) There are many time out settings on a supported IIS release, so you have to describe clearly which one you are talking about. 3) 5 web apps can be hosted in too many ways (same application pool? Multiple application pools?), so without more details there isn't much to discuss further either.

Comment: @LexLi  the timeout setting is under Default web site, Advance settings -> Behavior-> Limit-> Connection timeout.   my web apps is host under it and all with same app pool.

Comment: If you treat 120 seconds as baseline, then changing the value to 500 seconds almost has zero impact on web site performance, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits#attributes However, security risks increase significantly because DDOS can more easily exhaust this server now.